# Scrapy forloop node children

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="root-div">
            <h1>This is H1</h1>
            <ul>UL</ul>
            <h2>This is H2</h2>
            <img src="www.ttttt.com.png">
            <ul>UL</ul>
            <a href="www.ttttt.com">
            <h3>This is H3</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</htnl>
```

If I know all the tags, I can get all the information.

```
response.css('div.root-div > h1::text').extract_first()
response.css('div.root-div > h2::text').extract_first()
response.css('div.root-div > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

Buy if I don't know what tag is in `<div class="root-div">??????</div>`.How can i get every text.

For example

```
for tag in response.css('div.root-div ??????????'):
    if tag == "div":
       print("do something")
    else if tag == "img":
       print("do something")
    else:
       print("")
```

Comment: Have you tried BeautifulSoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to know the tag for each child element, do this:

```
for item in response.css('div.root-div *'):
    tag = item.root.tag
    if tag == 'div':
        # ...
```

However, if you really just wanted the text for the child elements, do this:

```
for text in response.css('div.root-div ::text').getall():
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank u for your help.